# How to change a part of the URL in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

How can I change this url:

```
schoolportal/schoolportal/login
```

To this url:

```
schoolportal/schoolportal/studentportal
```

So that if a user will click logout and press back, he will not be re-logged in.

Answer (score 1):

Sure he will not be re-logged in ! 
That your registration library will redirect user to a specified URL such like schoolportal/schoolportal/studentportal whenever the user try to access any link if he does not have access to.

You should add a script like this in your construct:

```
if (!$this->ion_auth->logged_in()) {
    redirect('auth/login', 'refresh');
}
```

Comment: I am very new to codeigniter, and I have no idea what this is. Can you elaborate your answer?

Comment: I can recommend you to use (auth library) to login to your site, which is good for codeigniter